# Need to get User Availability for all users when Application starts and change notification from MS EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server

My requirement is :

Req 1. When my application start then it should get the User Availability (e.g Busy, meeting etc) for many user (>1000).

Req 2. My application should get the notification for change in User Availability.

I saw many discussions about push notification for getting User Availability when status changes in exchange server (2010). But I did not get any way from which I can use “Push notification” to get the User Availability for all users when Application start.